# How to split a list in to multiple dictionaries with the same key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list with the following values:

['AAAAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBB','CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC']

I want to split this list in to multiple dictionaries with the same key
For example:

{'text': 'AAAAAAAAAA'}
{'text': 'BBBBBBBBB'}

Comment: This is a simple dict comprehension that iterates through the list.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is it kosher to just ask why you want to do this?  I'm very curious.

Comment: I am sending data to a Slack Webhook and the structure requires to be in this specific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list of strings is called list_of_string, you can use the following list comprehension to create a list of all these new dictionaries

```
text = 'text'
dict_list= [ {text : string} for string in list_of_strings ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
input_list = ['AAAAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBBB','CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC']

out_put_list = []
for item in input_list:
    out_put_list.append({'text': item})


print(out_put_list)
```

Or

```
output_list_1 = [{'text': item} for item in input_list]
print(output_list_1)
```